# Quarkus Rest Client not inject ConfigProperty in implementation of ClientHeadersFactory

Tags: java, quarkus

**Describe the bug**
I'm using MP Rest Client to call another Rest Service from my service implementation and want to overwrite some header attributes by using `@ClientsHeadersFactory`, but when I using `@Inject` to use another CDI Beans then a `NullpointerException` is raised.
With Micro Profile Rest Client 1.4 there is the possibility to use '@Inject' if your implementation is managed by CDI. This allows you to inject secrets for example or any other CDI bean to calculate a header value.

**Expected behavior**
injected ConfigProperty is available and not null

**Actual behavior**
NullpointerException is occur in update method of implementation of ClientHeadersFactory.

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Create a implementation class of ClientHeadersFactory and override update method

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClientHeadersFactory implements ClientHeadersFactory {

  
    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "secrets.value")
    private String secretValue;

    @Override
    public MultivaluedMap<String, String> update(MultivaluedMap<String, String> incomingHeaders, MultivaluedMap<String, String> clientOutgoingHeaders) {

        System.out.println("--- Incoming headers of the JAX-RS environment");
        incomingHeaders.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));

        System.out.println("--- Specified outgoing headers of the Rest Client");
        clientOutgoingHeaders.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));

       
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> resultHeader = new MultivaluedHashMap();
        resultHeader.putAll(incomingHeaders);
        resultHeader.putAll(clientOutgoingHeaders);
        
        //here is the NullpointerException raised
        resultHeader.add("X-Secret-Header", secretValue);

        System.out.println("--- Header of the Rest Client after merging");
        resultHeader.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));

        return resultHeader;
    }

}
```

2. Register your implemented ClientHeadersFactory in your Rest Client interface by using `@RegisterClientHeaders()`

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "remote-restservice")
@RegisterClientHeaders(MyClientHeadersFactory.class)
public interface RemoteRestService
{

    @POST
    @Path("/doSomeStuff")
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    Response createStuff( @Valid Stuff stuff);
}
```

3. 

**Configuration**

```
# Add your application.properties here, if applicable.
remote-restservice/mp-rest/url=http://localhost:9090/service
secrets.value=test
```

**Screenshots**
(If applicable, add screenshots to help explain your problem.)

**Environment (please complete the following information):**

- Output of `uname -a` or `ver`:
- Output of `java -version`:
- GraalVM version (if different from Java):
- Quarkus version or git rev: 1.5.2-FINAL
- Build tool (ie. output of `mvnw --version` or `gradlew --version`):

**Additional context**
(Add any other context about the problem here.)

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it has been fixed in Quarkus 1.8.